# SSIS : Conversion text stream DT_TEXT to DT_WSTR

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

I am creating a package in SSIS, and want to convert a file with one large column into multiple columns.

I have a table containing several rows with a single column of raw data.  The data was copied from a notepad file, and each row contains pipe delimiters to separate each column, but because it is a notepad file, each row is copied as one large column.  I want to convert each column per row to multiple columns based on their start/end positions.

I tried using SSIS Derived Column Transformation with the `SUBSTRING` function, but the Data Type is automatically populated as `text stream[DT_TEXT]`, and I get the following error:

> Error at [Derived Column[113]];  The function “SUBSTRING”
>   does not support the data type “DT_TEXT” for parameter number 1.  The
>   type of the parameter could not be implicitly cast into a compatible
>   type for the function.  To perform this operation, the operand needs
>   to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.
>
> Error at [Derived Column[113]];  Evaluating function
>   'SUBSTRING' failed with error code 0xC0047089.
>
> Error at [Derived Column[113]];  Computing the expression
>   "SUBSTRING[RawData],1,5)" failed with error code 0xC00470C5.  The
>   expression may have errors, such as divide by zero, that cannot be
>   detected at parse time, or there may be an out-of-memory error.
>
> Error at [Derived Column[113]];  The expression
>   "SUBSTRING[RawData], 1,5)" on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column
>   Output].Coluns[Derived Column 1] is not valid
>
> Error at [Derived Column[113]];  Failed to set property
>   "Expression" on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column
>   Output].Columns[Derived Column 1]. "

When I review other Derived Column Transformation illustrations utilizing `SUBSTRING` with a file containing individual columns, I notice the Data Type is shown as `DT_WSTR`.

Do I need to convert to this Data Type?  If so, how do I explicitly cast `DT_TEXT` data types to `DT_WSTR` with a cast operator in SSIS Derived Column Transformation?

Otherwise, how else could I handle this conversion?

```
Derived Column Name: EmployerNo
Derived Column:      Replace 'RawData'
Expression:          SUBSTRING( [RawData], 1, 5 )
Data Type:           text stream[DT_TEXT]
```

I expect the RawData column to be split up (converted) into 8 different columns based on their start and end positions.

Answer (score 2):

Refering to [SUBSTRING (SSIS Expression) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/substring-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns the part of a **character expression** that starts at the specified position and has the specified length.

You have to convert `DT_TEXT` column to `DT_STR`/`DT_WSTR` before using `Substring()` function, you can do this using a Script Component, you can use a similar function:

```cs
string BlobColumnToString(BlobColumn blobColumn)
{
    if (blobColumn.IsNull)
        return string.Empty;

    var blobLength = Convert.ToInt32(blobColumn.Length);
    var blobData = blobColumn.GetBlobData(0, blobLength);
    var stringData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(blobData);

    return stringData;
}
```

Or if the `DT_TEXT` length doesn't exceed the `DT_STR` length limit try using the following SSIS expression:

```
SUBSTRING( (DT_STR,1252,4000)[RawData], 1, 5 )
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, Hadi.  

I will try both proposed solutions when I get to work on Monday and let you know my results.  Just a question about the 1st solution.  Where would I insert the "string BlobColumnToString(BlobColumn blobColumn)" expression, would I need to include a Script task, and is this C# coding?

Comment: You have to define this function within a script component and use it as following: `Row.StrColumn = BlobColumnToString(Row. BlobColumn) ;`

Comment: Hi Hadi,I tried using your suggested solution of:
SUBSTRING( (DT_STR,1252,4000) [RawData], 1, 5 )
but got a similar error as mentioned in by first post along with error code of 0xC00470AA.  Then I replaced it with:
SUBSTRING( (DT_WSTR,1252,4000) [RawData], 1, 5 ) 
and still got a similar error message, except that the second error message did not give me an error code.  

Also, I don't quite understand where to place the follow statement with the Script Component:
Row.StrColumn = BlobColumnToString(Row. BlobColumn) ;

Also, what is blockLength, blobColumn, blobData and stringData?

Comment: @SoniaScott try using a data conversion transformation to convert to dt_wstr then add a derived column to extract Substring . I think it should work

Comment: Hi Hadi, I converted to DT-STR in a previous conversion step, and was successfully able to use the SUBSTRING in a Derived Column step to create several columns with Data Type DT_WSTR using the following statement:  SUBSTRING([Copy of RawData],1,5).  But I have another problem.  The file is variable length and delimited by the pipe "|" delimiter.  Is it possible to separate each column using Derived Column Transformation?

Comment: @SoniaScott you can use `TOKEN()` and `TOKENCOUNT()` functions

Comment: @SoniaScott check this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435110/treating-a-tab-delimted-column-as-a-bulk-insert-in-ssis/57436292#57436292

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the TOKEN() function.  I used code:  TOKEN([Copy of RawData],"\\|",1), and it worked perfectly for 1 file.  For the other file, I converted the data from DT_TEXT to DT_STR but got message:  Error: 0xC002F446 at 14a-Copy Rawdata to OLEDBTable, Dest [81]: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "Empl Id" column. The binding status was "DT_TEXT". The data flow column type is "DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION". The conversion from the OLE DB type of "DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN" to the destination column type of "DBTYPE_VARCHAR" might not be supported by this provider.

Comment: @SoniaScott it would be better to ask a new question where you mention the message, screenshots.

Comment: Hi Hadi, I see the problem now but don't know how to resolve it.  The previous file had nvarchar fields, and worked perfectly when converted to Unicode string [DT_WSTR].  The new file has varchar fields and gives error "Columns "Empl ID" and "Empl id" cannot convert between Unicode and non-Unicode string data types."  Right-clicking the task, going to Advanced Editor, then Input and Output Properties, External Columns, I notice the Data Types were already string[DT-STR].  When I tried changing them to Unicode string[DT_WSTR], they did the take the change.  What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: @SoniaScott you need to ask a new question and to provide an example of each file content and to show some screenshots of the package data flow task + error message. I cannot help you with just providing new error messages every time.

Comment: OK,  I will start a new question.  Just need to figure out how to include screen shots :). Thanks again.

Comment: @Sast77 check the following meta link to read on how to add screenshots https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post

Comment: @Sast77 also if my answers solved the problem mentioned in this question, you can [mark it as accepted to close this one](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I got it to work.  Thanks you.  First I had to understand the difference between Unicode (DT_WSTR or nvarchar) and non-Unicode (DT_STR or varchar).  I had to do 5 dataflow steps in single ControlFlow to achieve copy of the varchar file.  Step 1: OLE DB RawData source table.  Step 2: Convert all columns from DT_TEXT to DT_STR to get DataType DT_WSTR in Derived Column dataflow.  Step 3 Derived Column: Use Expression "TOKEN([Copy of RawData],"\\|",1)" to separate delimited columns.  Step 4: Convert from Unicode DT_WSTR to non-Unicode DT_STR.  Step 5: Map to (non-Unicode) OLE DB Destination Table.

Comment: @Sast77 then no more need for a new question. Congrats