# Treating a tab-delimted column as a bulk insert in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, sql-server-2017

I am importing a flat file with the following format:

```
H(tab)OrderNumber(tab)CustomerNumber(tab)ERPMessage
D(tab)OrderNumber(tab)ItemNumber(tab)ItemDescription(tab)ItemPrice(tab)Qty
D(tab)OrderNumber(tab)ItemNumber(tab)ItemDescription(tab)ItemPrice(tab)Qty
.
.
.
```

I am BULK LOADing the file using a format file to a staging table that looks like this:

```
RecordType varchar(1)
RecordDetail varchar(MAX)
```

so when it hits my staging table, it looks like this:

```
RecordType | RecordDetail
----------------------------------------------------------
H          | OrderNumber(tab)CustomerNumber(tab)ERPMessage
D          | OrderNumber(tab)ItemNumber(tab)ItemDescription(tab)ItemPrice(tab)Qty
D          | OrderNumber(tab)ItemNumber(tab)ItemDescription(tab)ItemPrice(tab)Qty
```

In my control flow, I set a variable (strSubfolder) based on the name of the subfolder the file is loaded from in my ForEach loop (ie: Sub_1, Sub_2, etc).

In my data task, I read the staging table and peform a conditional split based on the RecordType, and creating derived columns based on the strSubfolder variable.  What I need to be able to do is parse The RecordDetail field into its respective Header (H) and Detail(D) tables, and include the strSubfolder as a derived column to each table:

```
[Header table]
OrderNumber | SubFolder | CustomerNumber | ERPMessage
-----------------------------------------------------

[Detail table]
OrderNumber | SubFolder | ItemNumber | ItemDescription | ItemPrice | Qty
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I parse the RecordDetail field of my staging table, essentially treating it like its own BULK INSERT?  Am I going about this in the entirely wrong way?

Comment: are you sure it's tab delimited?  This feels like ragged right format to me.  Where based on each record type the row of data has it's own fixed width definition.

Comment: it is most definitely tab delimited.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using derived columns to populate these 7 columns, you can use `TOKEN()` function with SSIS conditional operators `? :`:

*OrderNumber*

```
TOKEN([RecordDetail],"\t",1)
```

*CustomerNumber*

```
[RecordType] == "H" ? TOKEN([RecordDetail],"\t",2) : NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
```

*ERPMessage*

```
[RecordType] == "H" ? TOKEN([RecordDetail],"\t",3) : NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
```

*ItemNumber*

```
[RecordType] == "D" ? TOKEN([RecordDetail],"\t",2) : NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
```

*ItemDescription*

```
[RecordType] == "D" ? TOKEN([RecordDetail],"\t",3) : NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
```

*ItemPrice*

```
[RecordType] == "D" ? TOKEN([RecordDetail],"\t",4) : NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
```

*Qty*

```
[RecordType] == "D" ? TOKEN([RecordDetail],"\t",5) : NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it's exactly what I needed.  I had to adjust my staging table RecordDetail field to 4000 (instead of MAX), as SSIS kept interpreting this field as DT_TEXT, and throwing errors on the TOKEN function

"Error at Parse order file (Header, Detail) [Derived Column [55]]: The function "TOKEN" does not support the data type "DT_TEXT" for parameter number 1. The type of the parameter could not be implicitly cast into a compatible type for the function. To perform this operation, the operand needs to be explicitly cast with a cast operator."

Comment: Try using `(DT_WSTR,4000)[RecordDetail]` or `(DT_STR,1252,4000)[RecordDetail]`

Comment: @Kulstad check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434730/ssis-conversion-text-stream-dt-text-to-dt-wstr

Comment: I just ran across an issue where the TOKEN function is treating consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter.  According to the accepted answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917758/why-does-ssis-token-function-fail-to-count-adjacent-column-delimiters), it is a "fault" in the underlying C++ function: strtok